# Finding $x$ such that $2^{4370} \equiv x \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 31)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to find $x$ such that $2^{4370} \equiv x \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 31)$?

The task is to compute $2^{4370} \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 4371$).

I know it's $4371=3 \cdot 31 \cdot 47$, so it's $2 \equiv -29 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 31)$.

With Fermat's little theorem it's $-29^{30} \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 31)$

$\Rightarrow 2^{4370} \equiv -29^{4370} \equiv -29^{145 \cdot 30+20} \equiv -29^{20} \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 31)$.

But how to continue?

I want to find a smaller number than $-29^{20}$ without a calculator. The calculator says $x=1$, but how to find it without?

Comment: What is $2^5$ congruent to mod 31?

Comment: It's $1$, but how do you get $2^5$?

Comment: You have $4370=5\cdot874$, hence $2^{4370}=(2^5)^{874}$. Now evaluate this mod 31.

Comment: $2^{4370}\equiv2^{4350}2^{20}\equiv(2^{30})^{145}2^{20}\equiv(2^5)^4\equiv1\bmod31$

Comment: Why are you factoring $4371$ or looking at $2^{4370} \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 4371)$? Some theory out there I am not aware of?

Comment: @CopyPasteIt: The original task was to show that $2^{4370} \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 4371)$, but I had some trouble to compute $2^{4370} \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 31)$.

Comment: $4371$ is a base $2$ [Fermat pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Did the OP demonstrate that $4371$ is a base $2$ Fermat pseudoprime? Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem I would think that mod $3$ and mod $47$ work remains...

Comment: @CopyPasteIt:  of course OP did not demonstrate that $4371$ is a base $2$ Fermat pseudoprime (yet) -- OP here was having trouble computing $2^{4370} \bmod 31$, which could be one of the steps toward that -- but I thought you asked why $4371$, so I gave an explanation of why $4371$ would be of interest

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, it was of interest. #rustyMathSkills

Comment: @Gerturter So did you complete your  original task? Did you save the best (the most challenging part) $\quad  2^{4370} \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 47) \quad$ for last?

Comment: @CopyPasteIt: Yes, I got the result. Since $-45^{46} \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 47)$, it's $2^{4370} \equiv -45^{4370} \equiv -45^{94 \cdot 46+46} \equiv -45^{46} \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 47)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to proceed is to find an $n$ to get $2^n$ close (either on the left or right) of $31$.

Well

$\quad 2^5 = 32 \equiv 1 \;(\text{ mod 31})$

Couldn't come out that much better; yes, $0 \lt 1$, but...

So

$\quad \displaystyle 2^{4370} = ({2^5})^{874}  \equiv (1)^{874} \;(\text{ mod 31})  \equiv 1 \;(\text{ mod 31})$

---

Fermat's little theorem works like a charm for modulus $3$ (resp. $47$) since $3 -1 = 2$ divides $4370$ (resp. $47 - 1 = 46$ divides $4370$). But even though $30$ doesn't divide $4370$, we can still use it when working in modulus $31$. Copying 
J.W.Tanner's comment,

$\quad 2^{4370}\equiv2^{4350}2^{20}\equiv(2^{30})^{145}2^{20}\equiv 2^{20} \bmod31$

Applying any 'divide and conquer' tactic you'll find that

$\quad 2^{20} \equiv1\bmod31$